# How to debug hacked Linux Kernel code

Tags: linux-kernel

I am newbie in this filed.
I don't have no good way to debug it. Just build it, reboot and run.
Any hint is very appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify: Did you build it, booted it and run it, or is that something you want to do? Have you looked at some web resources? The kernel development community is kind of large, there should be some help for you out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are hacking, it might be better to use UML (User Mode Linux). If you're messing with non-hardware dependent code, then I think it will help a great deal.

UML allows you to compile the kernel as an ordinary user mode program, and run it as any other application on your system. Because it runs like a regular application, you can very easily debug it with gdb, or any other debugger of choice.

[Here's a good start for UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux)

Comment: Similar to your approach, I've had great success using VMware Workstation to debug custom kernels.  GDB is able to connect to a running VM's kernel as if it were just another program.  Directions are at http://stackframe.blogspot.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to start from reading [4th chapter ("Debugging Techniques")](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch04.pdf) of classical [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book.